# Laravel Queries: 'lists' method

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

The 'lists' method surely does retrieve a list of column's values, but I want the method to retrieve the values but without duplication, how to achieve that?

```
    $types = DB::table('events')->lists('type');
```

Comment: If you are doing database normalization correct your events table should only have unique event-types right?

Maybe i misunderstand your Q, do you have multiple event-types that are identical? It is possible to filter them, but then the relationships kind of brake.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Patrik, think of 'type' as a way to categorize 'events'....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to get just distinct values, you should do:

```
$types = DB::table('lists')->distinct()->lists('type');
```

Comment: Thanks to you Antonio,

i've been reading your answers all over the stack about laravel and many other things, and haven't seen such complete answers anywhere else, wanted to thank you myself, and now I got the chance